# Get total row count after row insertion?

Tags: mysql, sql

Apologies for the super-newbie question but I'm having a surprisingly difficult time finding out whether what I want to do is possible even though it seems basic. I'd like to insert a row in a database and then get the total row count (not total affect row count). I tried:

```
INSERT INTO apples (type, number) VALUES ('sour', 3) RETURNING COUNT(*);
```

but this gives an error. I also found and tried the `ROW_COUNT()` function, like so

```
INSERT INTO apples (type, number) VALUES ('sour', 3); SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

but this seems to return an affected row count of some kind. What am I doing wrong and is this possible? Thanks and sorry if I missed an existing post, but all the posts I found were for counting affected rows, whereas I just want a total row count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
INSERT INTO apples (type, number) VALUES ('sour', 3); SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfApples FROM apples;
```

Comment: thanks a lot that was exactly what I needed. It works on command line of MySQL but doesn't seem to work with PHP PDO's. Any idea why this might not be the case?

Comment: I am glad to help. I am not sure, dont know php well.. It might be related to apostrophes, try " instead of '. If I were you, I would try to get and investigate how php returns the query string in debug mode.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli it will still be considered a separate query if I am not wrong? I mean,will it not perform separate I/O or request?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the ID of the last entered row (assuming ID is auto_increment), you can do this:

```
insert into apples (type, number) values ('sour', 3);
select last_insert_id();
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

If you want to get a count of records in the table, do this:

```
select count(*) from apples;
```

If you want to find how many rows were entered or updated using your insert/update statement, you could do:

```
select row_count();
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count

Also look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//information-functions.html#function_row-count